# How to organize videoboxes by count of people in WebRTC Angular?

Tags: angular, webrtc

I installed this project which is in the WebRTC repository. In my project with a conference application, I want to reduce the size of the frames as the number of people joining the room (with a red frame) increases. So I can view all attendees without using scrolling.

Here is that piece of code:

```
<div id="app">
<form class="center bg-paint-white" *ngIf="!conversation" [formGroup]="conversationFormGroup"
    (ngSubmit)="getOrcreateConversation()">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Oda Kodu</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput formControlName="name" /> </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
    <button class="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!conversationFormGroup.valid"
        title="Konferans Oluştur/Katıl">
        Konferans Oluştur
    </button>
</form>
<div *ngIf="conversation" class="container">
    <div id="remote-container" class="fullscreen"></div>

    <div id="local-container" [ngClass]="{ over: remotesCounter > 0 }">
        <video #localVideo autoplay playsinline></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Example]